# Can't go down mat-option list via cursor arrow

Tags: angular, typescript

After if autocompletes with the mat-options, if I hit the down arrow then it selects the first option everytime. I can't get to the second option via down arrow. Only via mouse click. I can use the mouse and click the correcty option and it does GET like I want, but not cursor arrow. How can I get the autocomplete to let me go down the list via down cursor arrow? I have a feeling it has something to do with onKeySearch() affecting it, but not sure how to stop it from happening. I appreciate any help!

component

```
  private onKeySearch(event: any, usernameLabel: string) {
    var $this = this;
    this.timeout = setTimeout(function() {
      if (event.keyCode !== 13) {
        $this.executeListing(event.target.value);
      }
    }, 1000);

    for (const post of this.posts) {
      if (usernameLabel === "username1") {
        if (event.target.value === post.username) {

          this.foundUser = true;
          this.searchedUserId1 = post.id;
          console.log("searchedUserId1");
          console.log(this.searchedUserId1);
          this.posts = [];
        }
      } else if (usernameLabel === "username2") {
        if (event.target.value === post.username) {

          this.foundUser = true;
          this.searchedUserId2 = post.id;
          console.log("searchedUserId2");
          console.log(this.searchedUserId2);
          this.posts = [];
        }
      }
    }
  }

 private executeListing(userSearched: string) {
    if (userSearched === "[Object object]") {
      return;
    }


    console.log(userSearched);
    if (userSearched.length > 2) {
      this.submitListingService
        .getUserIdAutoComplete(userSearched, this.userId)
        .pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy))
        .subscribe(res => {
          console.log("res");
          console.log(res);
          this.posts = res.posts;
          console.log(this.posts);
        });
    }
  }
```

html

```
  <mat-form-field class="formFields" id="username1Field" [ngStyle]="{'font-size.px': 12}" appearance="outline">
        <mat-label id="placeholder">Sender</mat-label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Find Artist" name="username1" aria-label="Number" matInput
          [formControl]="myControl" (keyup)="onKeySearch($event, username1Label)" [matAutocomplete]="auto" required>
        <mat-autocomplete autoActiveFirstOption #auto="matAutocomplete">
          <mat-option *ngFor="let option of posts" [value]="option.username">
            {{option.username}}
          </mat-option>
        </mat-autocomplete>
        <mat-error>User Invalid</mat-error>

      </mat-form-field>

      <mat-form-field class="formFields" [ngStyle]="{'font-size.px': 12}" appearance="outline">
        <mat-label id="placeholder">Recipient</mat-label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Find Artist" name="username2" aria-label="Number" matInput
          [formControl]="myControl1" (keyup)="onKeySearch($event, username2Label)" [matAutocomplete]="auto" required>
        <mat-autocomplete autoActiveFirstOption #auto="matAutocomplete">
          <mat-option *ngFor="let option of posts" [value]="option.username">
            {{option.username}}
          </mat-option>
        </mat-autocomplete>
        <mat-error>User Invalid</mat-error>
      </mat-form-field>


      <button mat-raised-button class="findButton1" type="button" (click)="search()">
        Find
      </button>
```

Comment: Can you please reproduce it using stackblitz or stuff like that?

Comment: one problem i see with your code is that both auto completes are using the same  name  #auto="matAutocomplete", you should change the second to something else (e.g. #auto2)

Comment: That did the trick! Thanks

Comment: i moved my comment to the answer, please mark it as accepted, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of your auto completes are using the same name `#auto="matAutocomplete"`, you should change the second to something else (e.g. #auto2)